# How do you add contents of two jars to uber jar with Maven shade plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have two projects. Project A has only resources. Project B has resources and class files. Project B has 3rd party dependencies. I have installed the jar for the project B to local repository (mvn install). If I use Maven Shade plugin in project A's pom.xml like this:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>com.company.*:*</artifact>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**</include>
                                </includes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then apparently also the *dependencies* of project B will be added to the jar, because I can see a huge number of class files in the uber jar. I only want to add the contents of the jar of project B to the uber jar (in addition to the resources from project A). How do you accomplish this?